# How to remove xarray dimension after adding another without deleting the data variables

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

I have data from ECMWF which when read into xarray looks like this

```
Dimensions:     (time: 424, step: 12, latitude: 3, longitude: 2)
Coordinates:
    number      int64 0
  * time        (time) datetime64[ns] 1990-03-01T06:00:00 ... 1993-04-22T18:0...
  * step        (step) timedelta64[ns] 01:00:00 02:00:00 ... 11:00:00 12:00:00
    surface     float64 0.0
  * latitude    (latitude) float64 41.0 40.75 40.5
  * longitude   (longitude) float64 -96.92 -96.67
    valid_time  (time, step) datetime64[ns] 1990-03-01T07:00:00 ... 1993-04-2...
Data variables:
    i10fg       (time, step, latitude, longitude) float32 4.876 4.637 ... 3.959
Attributes:
    GRIB_edition:            1
    GRIB_centre:             ecmf
    GRIB_centreDescription:  European Centre for Medium-Range Weather Forecasts
    GRIB_subCentre:          0
    Conventions:             CF-1.7
    institution:             European Centre for Medium-Range Weather Forecasts
    history:                 2022-04-23T22:18 GRIB to CDM+CF via cfgrib-0.9.9...
```

I've stacked the `time` and `step` dimensions to make a new one called `forecast`. I then added another dimension called `valid` and set that equal to the coordinate `valid_time`. Both `valid` and `fcst` are the same length, but I now want to drop the `fcst` dimension. However, when I do this, the data variable also gets deleted. Does anyone know how to fix this? Here is my sample code. There might be a better way to do what I'm doing, but I'm still pretty new to xarray!

```
ds = ds.stack(fcst=("time", "step")).transpose("fcst", "latitude", "longitude")
ds.expand_dims(valid=ds['valid_time']).drop_dims('fcst')
```

which leaves me with

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (valid: 5088, latitude: 3, longitude: 2)
Coordinates:
  * valid      (valid) datetime64[ns] 1990-03-01T07:00:00 ... 1993-04-23T06:0...
    number     int64 0
    surface    float64 0.0
  * latitude   (latitude) float64 41.0 40.75 40.5
  * longitude  (longitude) float64 -96.92 -96.67
Data variables:
    *empty*
```

I've tried setting `valid` as the index then dropping `fcst` but it still deletes the data variables.

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can't drop an indexing dimension without affecting the variables indexed by that dim. After the stack, can you use [`swap_dims`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/latest/generated/xarray.Dataset.swap_dims.html) prior to dropping? e.g. `ds.swap_dims({'fcst': 'valid_time'}).drop('fcst')`?

Comment: Yes this worked! Thank you! If you want to make it an answer I'll accept it as the correct one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All variables in an xarray Dataset must be indexed by named dimensions. You can use [ds.reset_index`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/latest/generated/xarray.Dataset.reset_index.html) drop any labeled coordinates associated with a dimension, but this isn't what you want. You can't simply do away with a dimension without losing the variables which are indexed with this dimension.

From the [xarray docs on data structures](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/data-structures.html#creating-a-dataarray):

> dimension names are always present in the xarray data model: if you do not provide them, defaults of the form dim_N will be created.

Instead, you can swap a non-indexing coordinate for an indexing coordinate using [`swap_dims`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/latest/generated/xarray.Dataset.swap_dims.html). This will swicth `valid_time` and `fcst` in your array, such that `valid_time` becomes the dimension which indexes `fcst` and any variables previously indexed by `fcst` (`i10fg` in your case).

So the answer is, after the stack but without `expand_dims` or `drop`:

```py
ds.swap_dims({'fcst': 'valid_time'}).drop('fcst')
```